# Visual Studio 2013 browser timeouts while debugging in IIS Express

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I am working on a VB.NET web forms application using VS 2013 Pro (Vr: 12.021005.1 REL) and IIS Express. After a certain number of rebuilds I'm finding that the application, despite building, times out in the browser (Chrome). The only way I have found to fix this situation is to restart Visual Studio, this obviously gets a bit tedious after a while.

I have recently switched from VS2012 working on the same application without issue. I'm also experiencing the same problem with another web forms application. What can I do to identify the cause of the problem? I've already tried disabling [Browser Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx) and temporarily switching off the Antivirus.

**EDIT**

When the application times out (usually after a rebuild or refresh) I am unable to stop the site from the system tray. I am however able to stop other sites in the solution, it's as if Visual Studio is locking this action. Killing VS instantly stops the site.

Comment: We've got the same thing going on in a web project that we've carried from VS2008->VS2010->VS2012->VS2013.   It's a ASP.NET 3.5 project.   We don't remember these issues in 2012 when it wasn't using IIS Express.  It runs fine the first time after a VS restart, then if you stop it and try to run again, you just wait...

Comment: Well I'm sorry to say I'm still stuck with this problem! I've reverted back to 2012 for now until a service pack is released.

Comment: Also debugging the project with "Local IIS" instead of running "IIS Express" (in the project properties) with VS 2013 seems to have improved the situation